# How do you kill the Wither in Minecraft PE using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I spawned a wither in my survival world and it keeps killing me. I would like to kill it with a command but I don't know how to use commands.

Answer (score 3):

`/kill @e[type=Wither]` should do the trick. The command finds any entity that has the type "Wither" and then kills it.

**Warning that the wither needs to be loaded in for this to work. You'd know it's loaded in when you see a "Wither" health bar at the top.**

This should work on **PE**/Bedrock and Java edition.